# Stack Overflow's live refresh features do not work when using proxy

Tags: discussion, status-norepro, notifications, live-refresh, proxy

Stack Overflow's live refresh gets you instant notifications without having to do a `F5` every time. But this behaviour doesn't seem to work when the browser uses some proxy connection to connect to the internet.

Foe example, at home, I connect to the internet directly without any proxy settings configured for the browser and the SO site refreshes normally. But when I use it from my workplace, I need to configure a particular proxy in the browser to be able to access the internet. In this scenario, the live refresh features of SO don't seem to work. I don't get any notifications as such. Only when I refresh the page by pressing F5 or reloading the page by clicking in the question link again, do the notifications show up.

Why is it so? Is there a no live refresh feature in place which blocks connections from a proxy IP? I'm really not sure how the live refresh feature works, but I really cannot understand why using a proxy setting in the browser would not refresh the site on its own. Can anybody please throw some light on this issue?

**Edit:** This is the [URL to the result](http://websocketstest.com/result/262635) I got on opening the Web sockets test site. The result was **It might work for you**. But unfortunately its still not working for me. Any ideas?!

Comment: Live refresh depends on web sockets working. If they don't work (as would likely be the case with a misbehaving proxy), it will not work.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is a misbehaving proxy? Because, as far as I know, the proxy I use at my workplace has no restrictions and we can freely access the internet without any other glitches. The auto-refresh of a site like Cricinfo works just fine.

Comment: In this context, a proxy that blocks web sockets.

Comment: What does http://websocketstest.com/ give you? If all that reports fine, then *maybe* Stack Exchange can improve something.

Comment: @Arjan - That's a great site(I never knew such a site even existed), but unfortunately I'm at my home right now, not at my workplace. Probably I can share the results when I go back to my office after the weekend?!

Comment: See also "What else do I need" in [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208)

Comment: @Arjan - I updated my question with the results from the site you suggested. Any ideas?!

Comment: @Oded - I updated my question with the results from the websocketstest site and the result was that websockets are supported. Any ideas as to why its still not working?!

Comment: There's a difference between supported and might be supported

Comment: @random - It says websockets are supported. Please check the result URL. The message I got after the test got completed was *it might work for you*. I don't know what that exactly meant.

Comment: Our websockets, like most websockets, work over port 80 which is blocked by your proxy as stated in your results.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - And exactly that doesn't work in my case. Anyways thanks for pointing that out to me. Just the final question, is there any work around for this already in place?! Or do I have to put up with this for eternity?

Comment: I'm assuming when we switch over to HTTPS websockets will work on both 80 and 443, but I don't know when that is.

Comment: And obviously: send those results to your system administrator. It might just be a configuration error?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - The live refresh seems to be working for me since this morning. Has the [switch you were talking about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200487/stack-overflows-live-refresh-features-do-not-work-when-using-proxy#comment640416_200487) completed?! In any way, this seems to be great as I no longer have to keep refreshing the page manually.

Comment: @R.J Yes, we're testing out HTTPS right now which includes HTTPS web sockets :)