# How do you get to see new questions first?

Tags: support, tags, tabs, new-questions

I refresh my http://stackoverflow.com quite frequently. I have added a few favorite tags which seem to be highlighted but most of the questions show after at least like ~3 minutes of posting. Some/most of them already have an answer so I find it difficult to get my hands on a question without an answer.

Obviously, since before the appear on my main page the must *be shown somewhere else* since other people get to them *faster than me*.

How do I get to see all new questions from my favorite tags right after they're posted/without the delay?

Comment: Click `Questions`. Then the `newest` tab. `F5`. `F5`. `F5`. `F5`. `F5`. `F5`.

Comment: I guess *live refresh* is not exactly working as intended(for you, may be because of proxy or something). In general, if you're following a particular tag, questions will be coming on to that tag instantly. Also, make sure you are on the *newest* tab in the questions section. Have a look at this for instance, [why live refresh may not work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200487/stack-overflows-live-refresh-features-do-not-work-when-using-proxy).

Comment: I think I may have discovered a slight bug in here:P

Comment: No, the page you loaded (the tag search) is cached too. You need to *wait* for new questions to appear on the socket. That means you need to be patient or pick a firehose like `c#` or `java`, and be patient some more. It is Thanksgiving weekend in the US, and the posting frequency has dropped dramatically compared to normal weekdays.

Comment: you mean `Thanksgiving` haha ;) `Lols giving`

Comment: Do you have a tab open for `[java] or [c#]`? Two new questions were posted in the past minute. Nothing new for `[vba] or [excel]` in almost half an hour though.

Comment: yes I get your point I know that mechanism well. I am just testing something else => clicking my favorite tag in main page and waiting till a new questions is posted works immediatelly -> which is what jergen proposed and I think he's right

Comment: Clicking your favourite tag on the main page uses the exact same mechanism as a multi-tag search.

Comment: i am not that stupid Martijn - I realize that, thats why I accepted juergen's answer It just took a few moments to verify that is the correct approach

Comment: @RichardTingle yeah it need more than 20-something characters in the about me section. I totally missed that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can get live refresh on your favorite tags!

Add your favorite tags to the search box with `OR` condition. For instance

```
[sql] OR [java]
```

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+c%23+or+php?sort=newest&pageSize=30)

On the result page go to the *newest* question tab. There you get new question **instantly.**

And in the browser tab you see a `(1) Newest ...` when a new question arrives.

Comment: the first question shown was asked 35 minutes ago and I am sure there are newer as I just answered one from 5 minutes ago.

Comment: I updated the answer. You need a `or` condition.

Comment: actually nope that still doesnt show them in descending order from NOW()

Comment: Click on the example. It works for me. Getting updates right now.

Comment: just did on other tag and it didnt work => didnt show the newest questions. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Try it with popular tags. *vba and excel* questions don't appear that often and you may not get a new question for that tags the next minutes.

Comment: it should not matter what tags I am using, should it?

Comment: @mehow: This is what I use; make sure your web sockets are working and you'll be notified of *new* posts within seconds of them being posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i pretty much instantly get notifications in the inbox etc so i dont think it's an issue of my own.

Comment: @mehow: for added efficiency: use the [keyboard shortcuts](http://stackapps.com/questions/2567/official-keyboard-shortcuts) to load the new questions with a single keystroke, then open the new questions with `SHIFT-ENTER` in a new tab, leaving the question list to load new posts in the background.

Comment: @MartijnPieters pretty cool app but i'd rather just click refresh or hit f5 and have that in a list - no work arounds

Comment: @mehow: Leave the tab open for a while. Try it with the `[c#]` or `[java]` tags to give you a real firehose of questions, and look at the posting times when new questions come in. Make sure websockets work with the [websocket test](http://websocketstest.com).

Comment: @mehow: Using F5 loads the *server-side cached page*; this does **not** include the new questions for up to 5 minutes! Do **not** use page reloading if you want to see the newest of the newest before everyone else.

Comment: @mehow: And just in case this helps you listen to my arguments: I am currently listed as #1 for the year on Stack Overflow. It is unlikely Jon Skeet is going to make up for the difference before the end of the year. I did this by a) knowing the answers and b) knowing the answers *first*.

Comment: i think the problem here might be the internal implementation of priority tags. Do you recon that C# and java are more frequently refreshed the Excel or VBA ?

Comment: @mehow: No, with this method you get questions instantly but VBA EXCEL questions are just not that often asked. Like every hour one question.

Comment: youre totally wrong juergen with your above assumption. I have been folowing the tags for a few months there is a new questions at least 10 min on average. Had 5 questions in the last hour in VBA tag which 60/5 = 12 minutes

Comment: @mehow: I wasn't going for an exact statistic. I just pointed out that these tags are not that popular and right know there is no new question for both in the last 30 minutes.

Comment: yep. no problem I don't want to start a fight, just saying

Comment: @mehow: OK. BTW I just got a new question for one of that tags via life refresh. So generally it should work. I don't know why it isn't for you. Sorry.